# How to shade the liquid using Radeon ProRender Add-on?

Tags: shaders, fluid-simulation, radeon-prorender-render-engine

I have bake a liquid simulation and want to shade the liquid. Yet it seems that the material is not showing....
I am using the Radeon ProRender add-on.
What should I do to fix it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The file:
[image]

Comment: If I bake the fluid sim I can see the liquid. But what really makes me wonder is why is there no *Rendered* mode for the viewport shading?! I have to switch to Cycles and back to Eevee to get the *Rendered* mode back. There is something weird going on: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKJqn.jpg. Which Blender version do you use?

Comment: I am using the Radeon ProRender Addon

Comment: Ah, okay. That's another render engine and explains the glitch that happens to me. Have you tried Eevee or Cycles? Disabled the addon? The problem might be related to the Radeon ProRender engine. Maybe it needs a special setting?

Comment: @Franc Please ad info about your render engine to title or description it is essential to get relevant answer. Thank you

Comment: Sure, thank you.